# What does this sentence about angina mean?

Tags: cardiology

I do not understand this sentence

> Angina can be treated ambulatory (in out-patient) in stable angina.

I think ambulatory refers to ambulatory ECG monitoring. 
So I understand this that you can treat stable angina based on ambulatory ECG. 
How do you understand this sentence about "ambulatory" angina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambulatory means there is no emergency and refers to where the patient is and not to the disease itself (here the patient is out of hospital): for example there is no need to perform urgent PTCA or other procedures related to unstable CAD (coronary artery disease).

Another option is - to hospitalize the patient to perform urgent or planned procedures if the patient is unstable and there is deterioration in his/her status which may worsen and threaten the life.

The key word in this sentence "**stable**".